# JavaFX - SetText() to TextArea does not execute until the program has completed

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently learning JavaFX. I am building an app that takes a file as input, connects to an external server, and returns the parsed results to a MySQL database. The core functionality is working fine, but I would like to have JavaFX update to the user, so that they know they are waiting to connect to the server etc. However, when the method is invoked, the text updates are not visible until the method has completed execution - I would like the updates to occur in real time. The offending method is below:

```
public void doBlast(){

    //this line is not updated until completion of the program - not straight away
    status.setText("Connecting to NCBI servers..NCBI" + "\n");

//Biojava API details extracted as it is not relevant

    BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = null;
    Scanner bufferedScanner = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriterXML = null;
    String rid = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {

        //this.getFasta() represents the input file
        bufferedScanner 
                = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader (this.getFasta())));

        //this.getTempXML() is a temporary file for temporary storage of xml output from the server
        bufferedWriterXML
                = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (this.getTempXML(), true));
        String line, nextline, query, xmlLine;

        //Loops for a specified number of times
        while (count < alignmentLimit) {
            this.setSequence_id(bufferedScanner.nextLine());

            //newline here
            bufferedScanner.nextLine();

            //this line from the file is used to search a database in the server
            query = bufferedScanner.nextLine();

            //this line is not updated until completion of the program - not straight away
            status.setText("Connecting to NCBI servers.." + "\n");

            //below service connects to server
            rid = service.sendAlignmentRequest(query, props);

            //results 
            InputStream in = service.getAlignmentResults(rid, outputProps);

            //this line is not updated until completion of the program - not straight away
            status.setText("Connected to NCBI." + "\n");                
            bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));                
            xmlLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
            while (xmlLine != null) {
                bufferedWriterXML.write("\n" + xmlLine);
                xmlLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();

                //  have to flush here so that it prints to file; 
                //  the file can then be deleted each loop
                bufferedWriterXML.flush();
            }                   
            count++;

            //this method removes specific strings
            this.removeAll("<?xml", "<!DOCTYPE", this.getTempXML(), this.getXML()); 

            //this method fills a database with the data from server
            this.xml2mysql();

            //file cleaning
            this.eraseData(this.getTempXML());
            this.eraseData(this.getXML());

            bufferedScanner.nextLine();

            //this line is not updated until completion of the program - not straight away
            numberOfRecords.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        }    
    }
    catch (Exception anException){
                anException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            bufferedWriterXML.close();
            bufferedScanner.close();
            bufferedFileReader.close();    
        }
        catch (Exception anException){
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
        }
    }
}
```

The setText() methods use a FXML-defined fx:id variable and the above method is in a controller.

Much appreciated if anyone can help me out. I have searched everywhere for a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: You are supposed to use Platform.runLater();.

Comment: Thanks...I am looking into this now.

Comment: @James_D - Yes, sorry I missed the question. It's slightly different as it's about updating labels but the process is the same.

Comment: In that question, though it's not immediately apparent from the phrasing of the question, the OP actually wants to update a `StringProperty` (called `labelString`). In your case, the `StringProperty` is just `status.textProperty()`, so really the difference is pretty minimal. (Is this a BLAST client, btw?)

Comment: Yes it is. I am putting a little client together for our lab. Many thanks for the heads up. Your comments were most helpful also, cheers.

Comment: Works a treat by the way...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a task or service which will place the loading of the file on a background thread.

You can hook into the methods called during the execution:

From Oracle documentation:

> Inside the call method, you can use the updateProgress, updateMessage,
>   updateTitle methods, which update the values of the corresponding
>   properties on the JavaFX Application thread. However, if the task was
>   canceled, a return value from the call method is ignored

If you perform the long process on the JavaFX Thread, the UI will be blocked and appear frozen.

Comment: Thanks...I am looking into this now.